# How to create interface with overloaded arithhmetic operators in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

To use it like:

```
public class myClass <T> where T : IArithmetic
//...
public myFunction(T A, T B){
    //...
    X = A + B;
    //...
}
```

So, I must somehow overload + operator for the T class.

Comment: Thx, James Guant, reading.

Comment: Can't do it with generics... which is a bummer.  I've always wanted this capability from .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to create interface for implementing operators.

According to the Standard:

> 13.2 Interface members
>
> *The members of an interface **must be methods, properties, events, or indexers**. An
>   interface **cannot contain** constants, fields, **operators**, instance
>   constructors, destructors, or types, nor can an interface contain
>   static members of any kind*.

Answer (score 1):

Can't create this restriction because the operator methods are static so they don't belong to the instance.
You can do some runtime check with reflxion and throw a NotSupported excetion if the T type don't support the required operation.